# iPad iframe scrollbar problem

Tags: ipad, scrollbar

I have a problem on iPad with this html definition:

```
<iframe id="DOMWindowIframe" name="DOMWindowIframe" src="'+settings.windowSourceURL+'" class="domWindowIframe" frameBorder="no" scrolling="yes">
</iframe>
```

The problem is that the scroll bar is not visible on iPad.
Is it possibile to fix this issue?

Kind regards
Massimo

Comment: iPad doesn't display a scroll bar. The iframe should be scrollable using a two fingered drag.

Comment: This iFrame is contened in a div: the problem is that the iframe shows over the div bottom line.

Comment: I think you want the overflow css property for your div set to hidden, auto or scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPad doesn't display a scroll bar. The iframe should be scrollable using a two fingered drag.

Answer (score 0):

And now, the two finger draging function is removed in iframe