# Fix safari scrollbar issue on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad iframe scrollbar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314922/ipad-iframe-scrollbar-problem)

I have an iframe inside a page and i don't see a scroll bar . I see some other suggestions  about using two fingers to scroll and its not working and its hard to expect users to use it that way . I have bunch of information which i can divide in to 10 separate pages . What will be best way to do this ?

I am thinking to use some kind of Jquery slider , paging plug in but need some advice what will suit best in this case .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314922/ipad-iframe-scrollbar-problem

Comment: Two finger scroll is not working and also if I expect users to do so I have to put a note on there which might not be good for user experience.

Comment: Closing question is not a solution here cause I already mentioned two finger scroll is working at all for iframe . You can search and see how many people are there complaining about two finger scroll is not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: Will this show 2 scroll bars ? one outside iframe and one inside ?

Comment: you can configure it as per your requirement just go through it